# Gtk, check if GtkTreeView is empty

Tags: gtk

I have following code to find if row is selected, which is selected and which text is in row of GtkTreeView. Code is in key-release event handler.

```
char *ntext;
if (gtk_tree_selection_get_selected(treeselen, &modelen ,&iteren))
{
    gtk_tree_model_get(modelen, &iteren, cEng, &ntext, -1);
... etc...
```

This works ok when my view is not empty. But when list is empty I get "segmentation fault".
I think that before this is needed to check if GtkTreeView is empty.

How to do that?

Actually, later I find if list is partially filled with clicking on unfilled area segfault happens too. So I need solution for that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, it appears when you say `GtkTreeView` is *empty* you mean in model ([`GtkTreeModel`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkTreeModel.html) which is implemented by [`GtkListStore`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkListStore.html) or [`GtkTreeStore`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkTreeStore.html) associated with your `GtkTreeView`) the data rows are added but are empty i.e. data is not set. In that case you need to check the value returned by `gtk_tree_model_get` (assuming `cEng` is valid otherwise you will get a warning message while running the program). Problem mostly is in `...etc...`. Just add a `NULL` check to `ntext` before operating on it.

```
char *ntext;
if (gtk_tree_selection_get_selected(treeselen, &modelen ,&iteren))
{
    gtk_tree_model_get(modelen, &iteren, cEng, &ntext, -1);
    if( ntext == NULL )
    {
       printf("Data is NULL!\n");
       /* Handle this case */
    }
   else
   { 
     .... etc ....
   }
}
```

This could also be the case in you button-press or release callback as well.
Hope this helps!

Comment: As usually, you identify a problem very well. Problem is in ...etc... I make here error in programming. How? I put my code in event handler which call other event handler with their code with "signal_by_name". This causes few errors which I described. After all I reconstruct code in separate functions which are called from handlers and after that code runs without errors and without need for more checking. "Another", thank you very much for your kindly help!!